# Which languages need the least paralinguistic features like facial / sound?

Tags: linguistic-typology

[Please tell me why you would down vote it in the comments]I am not sure about the technical term for it, but is there a language which could qualify as one with the least paralinguistic features? Where morphology and intonation cover it all? Where one does not need many facial / sound expressions e.g. snort for ignorance and stare for showing irritation?

Comment: What do you mean by "expressions"? For example, "The cat is out of the bag" is an "expression", and we would not say that talking in a nasal voice is "an expression", though it is paralinguistic.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! Expressions here are facial / sound expressions like snort to tell someone about ignorance or stare when angry.

Comment: I'd explain that in the question.

Comment: Any written language?

Comment: Any language written/ spoken.

Comment: @Gusto No, I meant that any written language obviously doesn't need facial gestures or nonverbal sounds.

Comment: @curiousdannii yeah, but adding the features would make it richer right? so, there is a need, but there is no option, even in English... we use (unsatisfactorily) phrases like "rolls eyes", where we can have an emoji/ GIF to compensate / make it more "expressive".

Comment: They are not richer, just quicker.  Any non-verbal cue can be described in an adverbial phrase.  Look for a language where users 'never' see each other (like what we have with phones; thus emojis to replace long descriptive phrases).

Comment: @aml ok I agree, but will​ replacement of this with some phrase get you the same effect? Also  can you replace this  , with robot/ I am feeling like a robot/ etc. (Which in fact would be conveyed by onomatopoeia or physical hand movement when facing each other)

Comment: The programming languages are like that.

Comment: @YellowSky I didn't really get that. 

Comment: I mean, the computer languages like C or Assembler need no emotions at all to be expressed.

Comment: @YellowSky it is because you don't talk to people with it.

Comment: You know little about programming languages, then.

Comment: Is this sarcasm?